# Swift 2: accessing the most newly spawned sprite position

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I use a `SKAction` `waitForDuration` to spawn a `sprite` every 5 seconds

```
self.addChild(enemy)
```

How can I access the most recent spawned sprite's position?

Answer (score 3):

Just save the Sprite each time you spawn one:

Somewhere in your initialisation:

```
var lastSprite = SKSpriteNode()
```

Then, in your enemy-spawning code:

```
addChild(enemy)
lastSprite = enemy
```

You might have to rework your SKAction to run a block with the 2 instructions, instead of just a single addChild. Alternatively, you might want to investigate enumerateChildNodesWithName to see if the last Sprite added is always the last or first Sprite returned.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `self.children.last` and cast it as `SKSpriteNode` to get the last item added to the array (of childrens)

Comment: I checked the documentation for children in SKNode and I think it's just a array of the node's children - do you know if .last is guaranteed to be the last node added?

Comment: Yeah `last` will get the last element added to the array. According to [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKNode/addChild:) `addChild` : Adds a node to the **end of the receiver’s list of child nodes**. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Steve Ives answer, but if the name of the sprite is not going to be used in your game, I'd have an integer variable declared, instead of a new SKSpriteNode, so that it wouldn't use as much memory. You could use something like this:

```
// Declare your integer when you initialise    
    var lastNode = NSInteger()

// You'd add your spritenode somewhere later in your code
    lastSprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "something")
    lastNode += 1
    lastSprite.name = "myName \(lastNode)"
    self.addChild(lastSprite)
```

Then whenever you want to access the last sprite, you'd use this:

```
    grabMeSprite =  self.childNodeWithName("myName \(lastNode)") as! SKSpriteNode
```

Comment: I don't think that lastSprite = enemy consumes any more memory, as it won't create a copy of the Sprite object, just a new pointer to the existing Sprite object.